Confusion regarding interior points and the set $A = \left\{ x = \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$
I'm having trouble understanding why the set $A = \left\{ x = \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ is said to have no interior points based on the definition of an interior point given in textbooks.
The definition I’m working with is:
A point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is an interior point of a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ if there is a neighborhood of $x$ which is entirely contained in $A$.
However, I don't fully grasp how this definition allows one to conclude that $A$ contains no interior points. In the reasoning I see in various texts, the argument is that for any point $x = \frac{1}{n}$ in $A$, and for sufficiently small neighborhoods around $x$, eventually there are no other points of $A$ inside that neighborhood. But at the same time, there exist larger neighborhoods around $x$ that do contain other points of $A$.
It seems to me that the definition only requires one neighborhood of $x$ to be entirely contained in $A$, not that all neighborhoods must contain points of $A$. So why does this reasoning about "small enough neighborhoods" exclude $x = \frac{1}{n}$ from being an interior point?
Where am I going wrong in interpreting the definition?
Thanks in advance for your help!

There are neighborhoods that contain points of $A$ (at the very least, $\mathbb{R}$ will always be such a neighborhood), but there is no neighborhood which is entirely contained in $A$. For example, take the point $\frac{1}{2}$. Any open neighborhood of it will definitely contain some points which are not in $A$, so it will not be contained in $A$.

In the definition of interior points, we require that there exist a neighborhood of the point that is entirely contained in $A$. You mentioned that "But at the same time, there exist larger neighborhoods around $x$ that do contain other points of $A$" --> This does not say anything about those neighborhoods being entirely contained in $A$, which fails the definition.

Proof: Obviously, $1\in A$ is not an interior point since for any $\epsilon>0$, if $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)\subseteq A$, then $1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\in A$.
For $n\geq 2$ and $\epsilon>0$, if there exists some $n_0\in A$ such that $(\frac{1}{n_0}-\epsilon,\frac{1}{n_0}+\epsilon)\subseteq A$, then choose $$\epsilon_1=\min\left\{\left\vert\frac{1}{n_0}-\frac{1}{n_0+1}\right \vert,\left\vert\frac{1}{n_0}-\frac{1}{n_0-1}\right \vert,\epsilon\right\}$$
We have $(\frac{1}{n_0}-\epsilon_1,\frac{1}{n_0}+\epsilon_1)\subseteq A$, but only $\frac{1}{n_0}\in A$(both $\frac{1}{n_0-1}$ and $\frac{1}{n_0+1}$ are excluded from the open set), a contradiction here.

Therefore, no point of $A$ is an interior point. Instead, the only boundary point is $0$ because every neighborhood of $0$ contains points from both $A$ and its complement (whereas $1$ is not a boundary point since for sufficiently small neighborhoods, there are only points from the complement). Right?
